# Cookies not working in https server asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

I am using both session and cookie to save information login details in sign in page and then checking this session and cookie before displaying details in the other page. Below is my code in sign in page

```
            Session["PartnerId"] = authenticate.ToString();

            //Cookie
            HttpCookie CookiePartnerId = new HttpCookie("PartnerId");
            CookiePartnerId.Value = authenticate.ToString();
            //CookiePartnerId.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
            Response.Cookies.Add(CookiePartnerId);
```

and here is the another page which retrieving session and cookie value

```
            if (Session["PartnerId"] != null)
            {
                PartnerId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["PartnerId"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                PartnerId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["PartnerId"].Value);
            }
```

But now what I am facing is session is working fine but when it expires the cookie is not able to set the value ie (it is null). I am thinking of removing the session but cookie alone is not working.
I observed that in my local environment cookie is working but it is not working on the server. Is this because of SSL (https) I have in server? Or is there anything related to cookie I am not doing? Please advice

Comment: I do not quite understand the problem you are facing. You want the cookie to have the "PartnerId" in it?

Comment: Yes Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["PartnerId"].Value) should not be null